# IdentityServer4 User.Identity.Name is empty

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

When I want to get the current user name in mvc client,it returns empty.
My config.cs code:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientName="Desktop",
                 ClientId = "Desktop",

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                RedirectUris =           { "https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5001/" },
                FrontChannelLogoutUri =    "https://localhost:5001/signout-oidc",

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "sms",

                    "mail.send",
                    "mail.search"
                },
                RequireConsent = false
            }
        };
    }
```

My MVC Client Startup.cs file:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddAuthentication(options=> {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies",options=> {
                options.Cookie.Name = this.Configuration["Cookies:IDS"];                    
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc",options=> {
                options.Authority = this.Configuration["IDS"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.ClientId = "Desktop";
                options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("sms");
                options.Scope.Add("mail.send");
                options.Scope.Add("mail.search");
            });
    }
```

My Login code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/Home/LoginPost")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginPostAsync(LoginInputModel model)
    {
        var context = await Interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(model.ReturnUrl);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //await this.signInManager.SignInAsync(new RWongAccountUser()
            //{
            //    PhoneNumber = model.Identity
            //},isPersistent:false);

            var signInResult = await this.signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Identity, model.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                            

            if (signInResult.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await this.userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Identity);
                //await this.Events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName, clientId: context?.Client.ClientId));
                await this.Events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(user.UserName, user.Id, user.UserName, "Desktop"));
                return Content("Succeeded");
            }
            if (signInResult.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return Content("IsLockedOut");
            }
            if (signInResult.IsNotAllowed)
            {
                return Content("IsNotAllowed");
            }
        }
        return Content("Failed");
    }
```

When I want to get the current user name like this:User.Identity.Name, it returns empty.
But I can get names from user claims.

How can I get the current user name via [User.Identity.Name] directly?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Then Microsoft and IdentityServer have different opinion on what the name of the claims should be, so you need to point out, which claim is the name claim, by using:

```
    .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
    {
        opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
        opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";

        ...
```

To debug claim issues, it can be very good to actually look at what does the access token actually contain? Use a tool like https://jwt.io/ to do that.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging JwtBearer Claim Problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Or better yet ```opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have resolved the problem!

Comment: Feel free to mark my answer as acceptable if it solved your problem